# print a number's digit in C

Tags: c

I'm learning C, and have a practice question.
I need to print the third digit from the right of a given number if it exists, or 0 if it does not.
(For example, for 1234 the program should print 2)

**How do I check if there is a third digit?**
I thought to check if it equals 0 but it can also be 0 (for example 1023).

This is my code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("enter num\n");    
    int num = 0;    
    if( scanf("%d" , &num) < 1){     
        printf("that's not a number");     
        return 1;    
    }
    printf("%d" , (num / 100) % 10);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So what is your program supposed to print when the digit is 0?

Comment: The very simplest way to get digits of a number, is to read it as a *string*. Then it's easy to get the number of digits (it's the string length) and to print a specific digit.

Comment: If num has three digits then it is at least 100. That you probably need to check.

Comment: zero is also a valid digit

Comment: `abs((num / 100) % 10)` is correct. `0` in 1023 is a valid digit too.

Comment: For what input does your program not print desired output?

Comment: I think more interesting question would be to print `-1` if the 3rd digit does not exist. In that case  `(x/100) ? (abs((num / 100) % 10)) : -1`

Comment: If there is no 3rd digit, then `num/100` evaluates to `0` which is already what you are supposed to print in that case. And `%10` doesn't change that. It seems you already have everything you need. Which numbers do you think would fail in your test? Your requirements don't contain any special handling for printing 0 because the 3rd digit is 0 or printing 0 because there is no 3rd digit. If you are not requested to do something, don't do it.

Comment: The point here is that the value you print is ambiguous, since you need to print 0 if it does not have a rightmost third digit or if it is zero...
I think @gulpr thought is better.

Comment: Does your program print the desired answer? What does it print if you input 23? Is it correct? What does it print if you input 1023? Is it correct?

Comment: for both cases it prints 0

Comment: @user1285764: Why should it not print 0 for both cases? You wrote “I need to print the third digit from the right of a given number if it exists, or 0 if it does not.” In 1023, the third digit from the right exists and is 0. In 23, the third digit does not exist, and you said to print 0. Both of those are correct according to the specification. So what is your question or problem? If you want different behavior, you need to change the specification of the program. What do you want it to do instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check if there's a third digit on a number, it suffices to check if the number is >= 100.

```
unsigned number = /* something */;
if (number >= 100) {
    printf("Third digit (from the right) is: %d\n", number / 100 % 10);
} else {
    printf("There is no third digit in %d\n", number);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is about integers and not floating point numbers, you can check > 99 and < -99.

All values >= 100 or <= -100 have three digits or more.

You could first take the absolute value of the number, but that doesn't change the functional behaviour...

Comment: no checks needed

Comment: depends on what OP specifically needs... The question in bold says "how do I check if there is a third digit?". You are right about the code being good though, but I thought OP wanted to add something new/extra or a way to distinguish between the two possible cases where 0 is the output.

Comment: will this check work for double too?

Comment: It could work for double if you are interested in the third digit of the integer part. If you are interested in the 1 in the number 0.123 for example, then no.
Someone else suggested reading the input number as a string, that might be helpful if you want the most general case of "third digit from the right".